# C# datetime index number of array

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I have two arrays, array1 has datetime data count by minute from 8am to 2pm and array2 has datetime data count by hour from same date 8am to 1pm.

I want to output the index number of two array that has same datetime.hour. and it should matchup the last available index number of array2 for all of the datetime data from array1 that later than array2.

for example if I have two datetime array like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
DateTime[] dateTimes1 = new DateTime[]
{

    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 15, 0),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 30, 1),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 45, 2),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 15, 3),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 30, 4),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 45, 5),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 15, 6),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 30, 7),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 45, 8),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 15, 9),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 30, 10),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 45, 11),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 15, 12),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 30, 13),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 45, 14),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 15, 15),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 30, 16),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 45, 17),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 15, 18),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 30, 19),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 45, 20),
};

DateTime[] dateTimes2 = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 0, 1),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 0, 2),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 0, 3),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 0, 4),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 0, 5),
};
```

this should be the output I expect:

```
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 1
5, 1
6, 2
7, 2
8, 2
9, 3
10, 3
11, 3
12, 4
13, 4
14, 4
15, 5
16, 5
17, 5
18, 5
19, 5
20, 5
```

This is what I have tried:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < dateTimes1.Length && j < dateTimes2.Length)
{     
    if (dateTimes1[i].Date == dateTimes2[j].Date && dateTimes1[i].Hour == dateTimes2[j].Hour)
    {
        list.Add(i);
        list2.Add(j);
        i++;
    }
    else if (dateTimes1[i] < dateTimes2[j])
    {
        i++;
    }
    else if (dateTimes1[i] > dateTimes2[j])
    {
        j++;
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[k] + " , " + list2[k]);
}
```

but it won't output the index number after 1pm.

Comment: where is `list` defined please do the following, `1. Show all relevent code 2. use the debugger to step through your own code` also how do you expect get proper results when one array is obviously larger / has more items than the other have you even stepped through the code..?

Comment: The last 3 items in `dateTimes1` do not match anything in `dateTimes2` on the year, month, day, and hour level.

Comment: @juharr it does match in dateTime2 on year, month, day, but not on hour, so I want to output the last three index number of dateTime1, with last available index number of dateTime2, just like the output I expect as I write above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your revised question hints at the use of generics, I'll provide an example of how you might accomplish this using generics and LINQ. The second part of the Tuple gets a bit complex, partly because your DateTimes all increment their seconds. Give it a look, run the code and see if this suits your needs...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateTime> byMinute = new List<DateTime>()
            {
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 15, 0),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 30, 1),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 45, 2),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 15, 3),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 30, 4),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 45, 5),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 15, 6),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 30, 7),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 45, 8),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 15, 9),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 30, 10),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 45, 11),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 15, 12),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 30, 13),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 45, 14),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 15, 15),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 30, 16),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 45, 17),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 15, 18),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 30, 19),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 45, 20) 
            }; 

            List<DateTime> byHour = new List<DateTime>()
            {
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 0, 0),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 0, 1),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 0, 2),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 0, 3),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 0, 4),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 0, 5),
                new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 0, 6)
            };

            var index = byMinute
                .Select(m => new Tuple<int,int>(
                    byMinute.IndexOf(m), 
                    byHour.IndexOf(byHour.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Year == m.Year &&
                        h.Month ==  m.Month &&
                        h.Day == m.Day &&
                        h.Hour == m.Hour))));

            foreach(var indexItem in index)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", indexItem.Item1, indexItem.Item2);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `while`'s conditional makes it stop when `j` reaches the end of `dateTimes2` array.  When you reach `j == 5`, the loop ends.

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < dateTimes1.Length)
{     
    if (dateTimes1[i].Date == dateTimes2[j].Date && dateTimes1[i].Hour == dateTimes2[j].Hour)
    {
        list.Add(i);
        list2.Add(j);
        i++;
    }
    else if (dateTimes1[i] < dateTimes2[j])
    {
        i++;
    }
    else if (dateTimes1[i] > dateTimes2[j])
    {
        if (j < dateTimes2.Length - 1)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[k] + " , " + list2[k]);
}
```

This only works if the second array runs out of data before the first one.